# pathlib mkdir creates a folder by filename

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I have the following preexisting folder in my machine

```
D:\scripts\myfolder
```

I want my script to create a folder named `logs` and create a file `log.txt` in it. So the path would look like

```
D:\scripts\myfolder\logs\somelog.txt
```

So I used

```
p = pathlib.Path("D:\scripts\myfolder\logs\somelog.txt")
p.mkdir(parents=True, exisit_ok=True)
```

Now

`print(p.parents[0])` ==> `D:\scripts\myfolder\logs`

`print(p.parents[1])` ==> `D:\scripts\myfolder`

`print(p.parents[2])` ==> `D:\scripts`

So, as per `Path.mkdir` documentation
`p.mkdir(parents=True, exisit_ok=True)` should create the folders `logs`, `myfolder` or `scripts` and so on if they don't exist.

But it creates a folder by the name `some.txt` inside `logs` folder, although it is none of the `parents`. Why is that so?

I understand that the workaround is to use `pathlib.Path("D:\scripts\myfolder\logs")`

Comment: From the ``mkdir`` docs: "Create a new directory at this given path." That is literally what ``mkdir`` stands for. The parents are created *in addition* when ``parent=True``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi but `somelog.txt` is not a `parent`

Answer (score 5):

The entire point of `mkdir` is to create the directory pointed to by its argument. Passing in `parents=True` creates the parent folders *in addition*.

> Create a new directory at this given path. [...] If parents is true, any missing parents of this path are created as needed; [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir)

If you want to ensure the containing directory exists, create the [*parent*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) of your path:

```
p = pathlib.Path("D:\scripts\myfolder\logs\somelog.txt")
p.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: But `somelog.txt` is not a `parent`

Comment: @ontherocks I haven't claimed that it is.

Comment: But that's the crux of my question

Comment: @ontherocks What part of "Create a new directory at this given path" makes you think ``samelog.txt`` has to be a parent? Note the emphasised *in addition* for the meaning of ``parents=True``.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way `Pathlib.mkdir` works. It can't tell if the final component should be a file or a directory. `parents=True` means to create *also* parents, not *only* parents. If the final path component is always a file, you could avoid it like

```
p.parents[0].mkdir(parents=True)
```